# Time use measurement

Tags: r, dataframe

Assume we have the following time use data for a 6-hour period from `4 pm` to `10 pm` I'd like to calculate the number of minutes that the same measurement was taken using the formula below. Where `u` denotes the number of minutes that two measurements were taken concurrently and p denotes the given position. The `ni` and `nj` demnote `Si` and `Sj.` How can I code this in R?

Formula:

[image]

Data structure:

[image]

Sample data:

```
structure(list(X1 = c("Si", "Sj", "Match"), X2 = c("A", "D", 
NA), X3 = c("A", "D", NA), X4 = c("A", "D", NA), X5 = c("A", 
"D", NA), X6 = c("A", "D", NA), X7 = c("A", "D", NA), X8 = c("A", 
"E", NA), X9 = c("A", "E", NA), X10 = c("A", "E", NA), X11 = c("A", 
"A", "15"), X12 = c("A", "A", "15"), X13 = c("B", "A", NA), X14 = c("B", 
"A", NA), X15 = c("C", "A", NA), X16 = c("C", "A", NA), X17 = c("C", 
"A", NA), X18 = c("C", "A", NA), X19 = c("B", "A", NA), X20 = c("B", 
"A", NA), X21 = c("A", "A", "15"), X22 = c("A", "A", "15"), X23 = c("A", 
"A", "15"), X24 = c("A", "A", "15"), X25 = c("A", "A", "15")), row.names = c(NA, 
-3L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(X1 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X3 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X4 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X5 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X6 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X7 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X8 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X9 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X10 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X11 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X12 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X13 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X14 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X15 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X16 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X17 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X18 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X19 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X20 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X21 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X22 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X23 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X24 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector")), X25 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"),  class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `apply` and run length encoding:

```r
RLE <- rle(apply(df, 2, \(x) x[1] == x[2]))

data.frame(position = names(df)[cumsum(c(1, RLE$lengths))[RLE$values]],
           length = (RLE$lengths[RLE$values]), row.names = NULL)
#>   position length
#> 1      X11      2
#> 2      X21      5
```

Comment: thank you for the solution. But what if in my dataset there are 1358 cases and not 2. How can I define then the RLE. Thanks